# Is there a pandas/python approach to change values of rows based on 3 column criteria?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with a table that looks like the one below:

```
   ID    NAME    DIRECTION    FOUND    LOST
    A     Rock      up           7        12
    A     Sap      down         15        17  
    A     Leaf      up          18        19
    B     Sap       up           5         9  
    B     Leaf      up          11        20
    B     Rock     down         22        23  
    C     Rock      up          12        14
    C     Sap      down         17        21
```

For each ID, I need to check where the NAME is Sap, then I need to check the DIRECTION. If Sap Direction = down then I need to invert the direction value for that ID. The ideal output is below:

```
   ID    NAME    DIRECTION    FOUND    LOST
    A     Rock    down           7        12
    A     Sap      up           15        17  
    A     Leaf    down          18        19
    B     Sap      up            5         9  
    B     Leaf     up           11        20
    B     Rock    down          22        23  
    C     Rock    down          12        14
    C     Sap      up           17        21
```

I'm starting with the group_by() method, and then I want to iterate through the groups. I am only able to print the key and value pairs, but I can't iterate over them.

```
for name,group in groups:
     print(name, group)

('A',   ID  NAME DIRECTION  FOUND  LOST
0  A  Rock         +      7    12
1  A   Sap         -     15    17
2  A  Leaf         +     18    19)
('B',   ID  NAME DIRECTION  FOUND  LOST
3  B   Sap         +      5     9
4  B  Leaf         +     11    20
5  B  Rock         -     22    23)
('C',   ID  NAME DIRECTION  FOUND  LOST
6  C  Rock         +     12    14
7  C   Sap         -     17    21)
```

Comment: JesusPena, I've voted to remove the [tag:r] tag, as it appears this has nothing to do with the R programming language; please do not blindly accept Stack's recommended tags, as it is an imperfect process that occasionally makes mistakes like this (though I have no idea why it thought "R" here). If I'm wrong, my apologies.

Comment: Are you changing only the values of `SAP`, because it seems the values of `Rock` changes as well when its direction is `up`

Comment: I want all the values inverted for an ID if Sap is down, so Rock and Leaf should also change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i would do this job:

```
s=set()
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.NAME[i]=='Sap' and df.DIRECTION[i]=='down':
        s.add(df.ID[i])
for k in range(len(df)):
    if df.ID[k] in s:
        if df.DIRECTION[k]=='down':
            df.DIRECTION[k]='up'
        else:
            df.DIRECTION[k]='down'
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! I was missing the range(len(df)) piece which did the trick

Comment: while it is the accepted answer, you should note that this is not using Pandas the right way - a vectorized approach within Pandas/Numpy will be much faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this without grouping:

```
arr = df.loc[df['NAME'].str.contains('Sap') & df['DIRECTION'].eq('down'),'ID'].unique()
mask = df['ID'].isin(arr)
df.loc[mask, 'DIRECTION'] = df.loc[mask, 'DIRECTION'].replace(['up','down'],['down','up'])
```